# Request with multiple array

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to do axios requests with a response like this :

```
//axios reponse
{
  "storeCountTotal" : "989",
  "total1" : "825282563",
  "total2" : "663647365",
  "total3" : "310893818"
  "Group1" : [ {
    "param1" : "test",
    "param2" : "test",
    "pram3" : "test",
    "param4" : "305427852",
    "param5" : "259865660",
    "param6" : "144522728"
  }, {
    "param1" : "test",
    "param2" : "test",
    "pram3" : "test",
    "param4" : "305427852",
    "param5" : "259865660",
    "param6" : "144522728"
  }, {
    "param1" : "test",
    "param2" : "test",
    "pram3" : "test",
    "param4" : "305427852",
    "param5" : "259865660",
    "param6" : "144522728"
  } ],
  "Group2" : [ {
    "param1" : "test",
    "param2" : "test",
    "pram3" : "test",
    "param4" : "305427852",
    "param5" : "259865660",
    "param6" : "144522728"
  }, {
    "param1" : "test",
    "param2" : "test",
    "pram3" : "test",
    "param4" : "305427852",
    "param5" : "259865660",
    "param6" : "144522728"
  }, {
    "param1" : "test",
    "param2" : "test",
    "pram3" : "test",
    "param4" : "305427852",
    "param5" : "259865660",
    "param6" : "144522728"
  }],
  
}
```

I created some models in typescript like this :

```
//Model.ts
export class Model{
var1: string
var2: string
var3: string

constructor(modelDTO: ModelDTO){
this.var1 = modelDTO.var1
this.var2 = modelDTO.var2
this.var3 = modelDTO.var3
}
}

export interface ModelDTO{
var1: string
var2: string
var3: string
}
```

and in my components i'm using a thing like this:

```
data: ()=>{
response [] as Model[]
}
async created(){
const modelDTO = await apiService.getStoresList() //Function with an axios.get and return an AxiosPromise<any>
    this.response = modelDTO.data.map((model: ModelDTO) => {
        return new Model(model)
})
```

And i would like to do the same thing with this axios response I sent just over.

Do someone have any idea how to use the same process have i done before with this response.

Thank you

Comment: So what stop you to define new Model?

Comment: I dont know how to define the model beaucse I have an array with 4 values and in this first array, 2 other one wih group 1 and 2

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read your question and comment 3 times and I still don't understand what you're asking or trying to do. Can you simplify the question?